# Hash tags for GIS Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

What hashtag(s) are used most often to reference http://gis.stackexchange.com and the community which enlivens it?

Twitter has the [@StackGIS](https://twitter.com/StackGIS) but that's just a robot, not conversation. The corresponding [#stackgis](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23stackgis&src=typd) is pretty empty, as is [#gisstack](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23gisstack&src=typd). The biggest, which isn't saying much, is [#gisstackexchange](https://twitter.com/hashtag/gisstackexchange) (too long to type I bet). Best I could find is compound [#gis #stackexchange](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23Gis%20%23StackExchange&src=typd)

Just curious if there's a converging trend I don't see.

Comment: I'm not sure that we need one, and so have never looked for one.  To me GIS SE is too broad for a Twitter hashtag to have much value.  If you found or coined one, what type of tweets would you envisage it being applied to?

Comment: #gistribe has two regular mods (underdark and myself) from GIS SE on Wednesday's 12 PST but we have a chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis but only seems to work with users in  it (blocked at work for whatever reason)

Comment: The https://twitter.com/StackGIS account uses the tag as a hashtag when posting

Comment: It always amazes me how much people use Twitter to talk about everything (and nothing?!)...Just keyword searching for 'gis.stackoverflow' yields tons of hits that aren't tagged with #gis or #stackoverflow, but instead individual topics, like #arcgisdesktop or #arcpy.

Comment: @PolyGeo I was inspired to blurb a half thought about GIS Stack being my go-to for peer reviewed content, contrasted against academia journals etc. (yes they're completely different beasts and it's apples to ...root tubers..., but that's what a twit's for) and didn't know where to fire it off too. #gistribe sounds good enough for now.